# Importing Thunderbird Email

Tags: thunderbird, import

I have two files retrieved from backup: Inbox and Inbox.msf. How do I import these into Thunderbird?

I tried copy/pasting them into the `C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Thunderbird\Profiles\<salt_name>\Mail\Local Folders` directory, but Thunderbird ignored them.

Answer (score 2):

Close Thunderbird and then rename it to something other than 'Inbox' (like 'RecoveredMail'). Depending on your setup (e.g. IMAP) Thunderbird won't be looking for Inbox folder in Local Folders, but only non-special folders (name it anything but Inbox, Drafts or Sent).  You can also safely delete the msf file, it's just an index and Thunderbird will rebuild it.